# Pod publishing messages with KafkaJs to Strimzi keeps crashing

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, apache-kafka, kafkajs

This is my [KafkaJs](https://kafka.js.org/docs/getting-started) based publisher client. I created a container image and submitted a `Pod` YAML to Strimzi broker.

```js
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs')

async function clients() {
const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-app',
  brokers: ['test-kafka-bootstrap.strimzi.svc.cluster.local:9092']
})

const producer = kafka.producer()

await producer.connect()
await producer.send({
  topic: 'clients',
  messages: [
    { value: 'Hello KafkaJS user!' },
  ],
})

await producer.disconnect()
}

clients()
```

My `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM node:14 as build_app

WORKDIR /

WORKDIR /app
COPY app .
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json .
RUN npm i
CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

My `pod` YAML.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: clients
spec:
  containers:
  - name: clients
    image: ghcr.io/org/clients:v0.0.0
    imagePullPolicy: Always
```

The `Pod` keeps crashing and `kubectl logs` does not show anything - its empty. A `kubectl describe` didnt' reveal anything either.

What am I missing?

Comment: Hello @cogitoergosum, Did provided solutions help you?

Answer (score 1):

The logs show nothing because 1) Your code has no log output 2) Your code only send a single record, and then stops, so the container exits cleanly; it is not a long-running service. You'd have the same issues with a simple `docker run` command.

If you wanted a long-running service, you'd need to wrap your code in a web-service (NextJS, Express, Hapi, etc), and then add a health check probe for the k8s Service.

Comment: Agree with all the points above. The question is, why does a successful publish (as you mention, "...exits cleanly...") result in `CrashLoopBackoff` status of the pod?

Comment: The `Pod` gets rescheduled again because `restartPolicy` defaults to `Always`; but, I don't get the reason behind the status `CrashLoopBackOff`. Why does Kubernetes think the `Pod` has crashed?

Comment: I'm not well versed in all kubernetes things, but I suspect it's because you have no health or liveness prove

Answer (score 1):

you can bring up the pod in sleep mode and from there you can debug, use below yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: clients
spec:
  containers:
  - name: clients
    image: ghcr.io/org/clients:v0.0.0
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: ["sleep" , "100000000"]
```

Now exec into the pod

```
kubectl exec -it <pod> -- bash
```

now execute

```
node index.js
```